# question about standards/conventions: occasional observation adequate for an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I would like some guidance regarding a heated comments exchange over [an answer I downvoted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942136/3044344).

**original question about file naming:**

> Are there any standard or guide to follow to know when to use [hypen] or [underscore]?

**objectionable answer:**

> Generally, use underscore to group words together and hyphens to separate them.
>
> e.g. **it_s-a-wonderful_world**, **the-world-is-wonderful**
>
> There's no real convention here but this is quite common and logical.
>
> **Update**: So to elaborate a bit farther on this when you have an adjective that modifies a noun or when two or more words are used as one unit whether it's a preposition/contraction or whatever then I'd use underscores to indicate that; otherwise I'd use hyphens to separate words apart in a single sentence.

I downvoted the answer and commented various ways such a schema is unworkable.

To which the author replied (snippet):

> You're taking things too far! trying to find reasons to downvote me where I explicitly said "There's no real convention here but this is quite common and logical." I didn't invent them they are just things I observed through many years of using POSIX systems, inconsistencies are completely irrelevant!

My gut says that merely observing a pattern in the field does not qualify it as an appropriate answer to someone seeking a "standard or guide".

Was my downvote warranted?

**EDIT**: just to be clear, my downvote was for the answer, not the question

Comment: "Was my downvote warranted?" -- I think so. Weren't it for the "standard or guide" delimitation, the question would fall right into "primarily opinion-based". It definitely doesn't need answers about arbitrary rules supported by unspecified anecdotal evidence.

Comment: I think that might qualify as an off-site resource request. It definitely is not a useful question, and the existing answer is basically "no". Nothing in that comment chain is particularly constructive.

Comment: just to be clear, my downvote was for the *answer*, not the *question*

Comment: I understand that, but if the question is a problem, it should just be closed and deleted. Problematic questions cause problematic answers, which cause problematic comments, and problematic meta questions. Get rid of the problem at the root.